# Parse XML using Groovy: How do I keep the CDATA when parsing a XML file

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, cdata

Using Groovy 2.0.5 JVM 1.6.0_31, I have created a script that takes an existing XML-file as input

```
def root = new XmlParser().parse(new File('filename'))
```

I parse the file and replaces certain attributes like this

```
root.Settings.Setting.each {
if (it.'@NAME' =~ 'CASEID_SEQUENCE_SIZE') {
   it.'@VALUE' = '100'
```

And then at the end writes the changes to a new file like this

```
def outputfile = new File( levelConfig.RESULTFILE )
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(outputfile)).print(root)
```

All this is fine, no problem, except when the XML has CDATA, like this

```
<HandlerURL>
   <![CDATA[admin/MainWindow.jsp]]>
</HandlerURL>
```

the result is then

```
<HandlerURL>
    admin/MainWindow.jsp
</HandlerURL>
```

#### Question is

How can I get my script to not do anything with the CDATA?

Comment: Had to change the write to file code to

    XmlUtil.serialize( root , new PrintWriter(outputfile))

or else the XML was just cut off somewhere in the middle of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found you can do:

```
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory

def xml = '''<root>
            |  <Settings>
            |    <Setting name="CASEID_SEQUENCE_SIZE">
            |      <HandlerURL>
            |        <![CDATA[ admin/MainWindow.jsp ]]>
            |      </HandlerURL>
            |    </Setting>
            |    <Setting name="SOMETHING_ELSE">
            |      <HandlerURL>
            |        <![CDATA[ admin/MainWindow.jsp ]]>
            |      </HandlerURL>
            |    </Setting>
            |  </Settings>
            |</root>'''.stripMargin()

def document = DOMBuilder.parse( new StringReader( xml ) )
def root = document.documentElement

use(DOMCategory) {
  root.Settings.Setting.each {
    if( it.'@name' == 'CASEID_SEQUENCE_SIZE' ) {
      it[ '@value' ] = 100
    }
  }
}

def result = XmlUtil.serialize( root )

println result
```

To get the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Settings>
    <Setting name="CASEID_SEQUENCE_SIZE" value="100">
      <HandlerURL>
        <![CDATA[ admin/MainWindow.jsp ]]>
      </HandlerURL>
    </Setting>
    <Setting name="SOMETHING_ELSE">
      <HandlerURL>
        <![CDATA[ admin/MainWindow.jsp ]]>
      </HandlerURL>
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</root>
```